# Vmware Server Installation in Linux

Tags: linux, centos7, vmware

We have a machine running Windows Server 2008 for Running virtual machines. We want to move this machine to the Linux environment. We will also install VMWare on the new operating system. We are considering using CentOS. Is there someone on CentOS using VMWare? On which operating system would it be advantageous to use VMWare?

Comment: this is off topics here. you should ask on [su] as this site is for programming questions...

Answer (score 0):

Please read supported OP Systems, by VM.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/vCenter-Converter-Standalone/6.2/com.vmware.convsa.guide/GUID-088E735A-CB88-4790-9BF2-EA0B9E34867F.html

A lot of people or company just using Windows. 
The question is not answered by forum, but helpful to decide: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/512089

Hope it helps!

Comment: Anyway , Linux or Windows, no matter both are good enough for VM workstation.